# View and/or Export all versions of a SharePoint List

Tags: list-view, view, export, version-history

I'm using SharePoint 2016 and need to analyze all the versions of a list.  How do I export all the versions into an excel file or access the versions in another way to do some analysis (using PowerBI)?  Not individual records, all records, all versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extract version history of individual items using PowerShell.

This script is a good starting point. You may need to adjust the script to your likings:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Test-bb3ed1ca